# Filtering WordPress posts by Taxonomy Term doesn't Work as expected

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created 3 separate post queries which display posts from my Events CPT.
After this I have created a dropdown to filter my posts according to the taxonomy locations.

The dynamic output of my Location terms is correct. However I can only display posts under the 'All' drop down selection, as the other options do not display any posts.

I have no console errors.

My Script

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // When the dropdown value changes
    $('#location-filter').change(function() {
        var selectedTerm = $(this).val();

        // Hide all posts
        $('.query-results').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.event-post').hide();
        });

        // Show posts that match the selected location term
        if (selectedTerm === 'all') {
            $('.query-results').each(function() {
                $(this).find('.event-post').show(); // Show all posts when "All" is selected
            });
        } else {
            $('.query-results').each(function() {
                $(this).find('.event-post[data-location-term="' + selectedTerm + '"]').show(); // Show posts matching the selected term
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My Template Code

```
     <?php 
// Query 1
$args1 = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'events',
    'meta_key'      => 'test',
    'meta_value'    => 'test'
);

$the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
?>

<div class="queries-container">
    <!-- Display filter DRopdown above queries -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location-filter">Location Filter:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="location-filter">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <?php
            // Get unique location terms from the custom taxonomy
            $location_terms = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                'hide_empty' => true,
            ));

            foreach ($location_terms as $term) {
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '">' . esc_html($term->name) . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Query 1 -->
    <div class="query-results query-results-1">
        <h2>Query 1 Results:</h2>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading1">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                        Expand/Collapse Query 1
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapse1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-bs-parent="#accordion1">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <?php if( $the_query1->have_posts() ): ?>
                            <ul> <!-- Wrap the list in a container div -->
                            <?php while( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : $the_query1->the_post(); ?>
                                <li class="event-post" data-location-term="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_query();   // Restre global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

    <!-- Repeat the same structure for Query 2 and Query 3 -->

    <!-- Query 2 -->
    <div class="query-results query-results-2">
        <?php
        $args2 = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'events',
            'meta_key'      => 'test',
            'meta_value'    => 'test1'
        );

        $the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
        ?>
        <h2>Query 2 Results:</h2>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading2">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        Expand/Collapse Query 2
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-bs-parent="#accordion2">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <?php if( $the_query2->have_posts() ): ?>
                            <ul> <!-- Wrap the list in a container div -->
                            <?php while( $the_query2->have_posts() ) : $the_query2->the_post(); ?>
                               <li class="event-post" data-location-term="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Query 3 -->
    <div class="query-results query-results-3">
        <?php
        $args3 = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'events',
            'meta_key'      => 'test',
            'meta_value'    => 'test'
        );

        $the_query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
        ?>
        <h2>Query 3 Results:</h2>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion3">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading3">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3">
                        Expand/Collapse Query 3
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapse3" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-bs-parent="#accordion3">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <?php if( $the_query3->have_posts() ): ?>
                            <ul> <!-- Wrap the list in a container div -->
                            <?php while( $the_query3->have_posts() ) : $the_query3->the_post(); ?>
                                <li class="event-post" data-location-term="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample example of your HTML structure from your browser so we could see `data-location-term` examples as well as a sample search term?

Comment: In your options you output `$term->slug` as the value, whereas in your data attribute, you use `get_field('location_term')` - I'm guessing these two are probably _not_ resulting in the same value ...?

Comment: @CBroe Yes this is an error. But it is not the underlying cause for why there is no output when a select the other terms from the drop-down form.

Comment: So you are saying both of these output the exact same value anyway? Because if not, then I don't see how you can say this was _not_ the cause of the problem ... you'd be trying to select elements by an attribute value, that they don't really have.

Comment: @CBroe location_term is obsolete. Its value has been previously removed. I will adjust code to reflect this.The issue is I have no output for any posts unless I select ‘All’.

Comment: So have you verified the values in both locations match by now?

Comment: @CBroe You are right about the inconsistency in the statement. I have edited my script, but it still does not output unless all dropdown is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @CBroe, I realised I was missing post data in the events post. Here is the working code.

```
    <?php 
// Query 1
$args1 = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'events',
    'meta_key'      => 'test',
    'meta_value'    => 'test'
);

$the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
?>

<div class="queries-container">
    <!-- Display filter DRopdown above queries -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location-filter">Location Filter:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="location-filter">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <?php
            // Get unique location terms from the custom taxonomy
            $location_terms = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                'hide_empty' => true,
            ));

            foreach ($location_terms as $term) {
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '">' . esc_html($term->name) . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Query 1 -->
    <div class="query-results query-results-1">
        <h2>Query 1 Results:</h2>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading1">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                        Expand/Collapse Query 1
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapse1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-bs-parent="#accordion1">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <?php if( $the_query1->have_posts() ): ?>
                            <ul> <!-- Wrap the list in a container div -->
                            <?php while( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : $the_query1->the_post(); ?>
                                <li class="event-post" data-location-term="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'location_term', true)); ?>">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

    <!-- Repeat the same structure for Query 2 and Query 3 -->

    <!-- Query 2 -->
    <div class="query-results query-results-2">
        <?php
        $args2 = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'events',
            'meta_key'      => 'test',
            'meta_value'    => 'test1'
        );

        $the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
        ?>
        <h2>Query 2 Results:</h2>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading2">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        Expand/Collapse Query 2
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-bs-parent="#accordion2">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <?php if( $the_query2->have_posts() ): ?>
                            <ul> <!-- Wrap the list in a container div -->
                            <?php while( $the_query2->have_posts() ) : $the_query2->the_post(); ?>
                               <li class="event-post" data-location-term="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'location_term', true)); ?>">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Query 3 -->
    <div class="query-results query-results-3">
        <?php
        $args3 = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'events',
            'meta_key'      => 'test',
            'meta_value'    => 'test'
        );

        $the_query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
        ?>
        <h2>Query 3 Results:</h2>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion3">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading3">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3">
                        Expand/Collapse Query 3
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapse3" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-bs-parent="#accordion3">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <?php if( $the_query3->have_posts() ): ?>
                            <ul> <!-- Wrap the list in a container div -->
                            <?php while( $the_query3->have_posts() ) : $the_query3->the_post(); ?>
                                <li class="event-post" data-location-term="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'location_term', true)); ?>">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    </div>
</div>
```